# extjs5: sencha app upgrade fails

Tags: extjs

From inside existing extjs5 application directory:

```
> sencha app upgrade path\to\ext-5.0.0
Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.116
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.Version.cleanVersionString(Version.java:169)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$UpgradeCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:226)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$UpgradeCommand.dispatch(AppCommands.java:335)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:71)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:139)
```

%100 the downloaded sdk is at `path\to\ext-5.0.0`

Trying to upgrade 5.0.0.736 -> 5.0.0.970

Same thing for `sencha app upgrade` and `sencha app upgrade -ext`

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem. You can try this:

1. upgrade Cmd only with `sencha upgrade`
2. then try again `sencha app upgrade`

If it fails, generate new app with

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/ext generate app --starter=no YourAppName your/app/path
```

That will skip the default starter app creation. Then you copy the old application files to the new structure, and finally run

```
sencha app build
```

I had to use the second approach: regenerate, copy, build.